# Ruby / Rails - Paperclip::Error in ModificationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, controller, paperclip

### Paperclip::Error in ModificationsController#create Modification model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'

---

**Error:**

[image: Error]

---

**Model:** modification.rb

```
class Modification < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :image,
        styles: { thumb: ["64x64#", :jpg],
        original: ['500x500>', :jpg] },
        convert_options: { thumb: "-quality 75 -strip",
        original: "-quality 85 -strip" }

    validates_attachment :image,
        content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }

end
```

---

**Controller:** modifications_controller.rb

```
class ModificationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @modifications = Modification.order('created_at')
  end

  def new
    @modifications = Modification.new
  end

  def create
    @modifications = Modification.new(modification_params)
    if @modifications.save
      flash[:success] = "Modification contributed!"
      redirect_to collection_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def modification_params
    params.require(:modification).permit(:image, :title)
  end

end
```

---

**Migration:** _create_modifications.rb

```
class CreateModifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :modifications do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :image_file_name 
      t.string :image_content_type 
      t.integer :image_file_size 
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Migration:** _add_attachment_modification_to_profiles.rb

```
class AddAttachmentModificationToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :profiles do |t|
      t.attachment :modification
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :profiles, :modification
  end
end
```

---

**Schema.rb**

```
  create_table "modifications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

...

```
  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "modifications"
    t.string   "website"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.string   "modification_file_name"
    t.string   "modification_content_type"
    t.integer  "modification_file_size"
    t.datetime "modification_updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared twice **`has_attached_file :image`** method in your Model: `modification.rb`

Try to delete very first one **has_attached_file :image** and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: If solution above doesn't work, try this one by replacing the line of code in your controller `modifications_controller.rb`: 

`params.require(:modification).permit(:image [:image_file_name, :image_file_size, :image_content_type, :image_updated_at], :title)`

Have you done migrations? Do you have these columns in your DB?

   `t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"`

 [https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start]

Comment: Good catch on the repeated declaration. I removed it from my code (including the excerpt in the question above). However, the same error message appeared. I edited my question by adding the migrations and schema. Any further guidance would help.

Comment: Apparently schema file shows that you don't have image fields in modifications table in DB.  You can delete this file: 
 `_create_modifications.rb` and add this code to your command line: `rails generate paperclip modification image` and after that run `rake db:migrate`, and restart server.

Comment: The issue was resolved by deleting one of the previous migrations and generating paperclip's solution, as suggested by @Blackcoat77.